# A shoujo manga about 32 year old makeup artist who travels back in time to her younger high school life

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, manga

I have been searching for this manga I read a while ago about a middle-aged make-up artist who reverts to her old high school self while remembering her first love that didn't work out for whatever reason. I don't remember correctly if she was bullied because she was really shy or if the first love was dead, but I remember her consulting her pregnant engaged friend before she went back into the past due to fact she was still a virgin at 32.

Answer (score 4):

This is *[Seishun Cinderella](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/seishun-cinderella)*.

> High school girl Shion decides to confess to the boy she likes. However, even before she can say "I like you", she receives her answer: "If you want to confess, at least do something about your appearance". **Ten years later, Shion works and has much more style**, but still can't manage to have a normal relationship with a man. Ever since she got that answer, time has stopped for her. By pure chance she finds a photo from that time and, as she tears it up, **she finds herself catapulted back to the same time as the photo**. The modest high school girl from ten years ago has returned, but now she knows how to put on makeup and dress fashionably. And so, Shion has a second chance to live her high school life and erase her regrets.

The synopsis is a perfect match for the question. The main character confesses to a boy she likes, but it turned down due to her plain appearance. She ends up working at a department store doing makeup for other people and is significantly more fashionable at this point. She still doesn't have a boyfriend, and her pregnant friend suggests she find someone at a mixer before she's too busy with her pregnancy and child to help her out anymore.

By chance sees a photograph of her old self, a female friend, and the boy she had a crush on. She tears it up and goes back in time to when the photo was taken.

Found by searching mangaupdates for the tags `Time Rewind` and `Make-up Artist/s`